# htaccess I want to make my user profiles 'pretty' as it were

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make my user profiles 'pretty' as it were. Here is the regular URL:
`site.com/user.php?user=Echo123`
I want this to become:
`Echo123.site.com`
Please help :) Im a .htaccess newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact your web hosting provider or go to your web console and Go To Domains->Your Domain->DNS->CNAME and input the subdomain Echo123.yourdomain.com then input the forwarding url yourdomain.com/user.php?user=Echo123

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/user.php?user=%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```